# Background looping mechanism in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm developing a simple simulation involving city budgeting for local officials to use. I have developed a map for the simulation and an algorithm that 'grows' the map when its function is called. Thus, `updateMap();` results in numerous changes across the field of play. Currently, I have this function bound to other mechanisms in the game, called once every time something else happens, for example. My question is this: is there any way to have something like this

```
while (true)
    setTimeout('updateMap();', 45000);
```

such that the map will update itself independently of whatever the user is doing and whatever is going on in the game. I understand that Javascript doesn't support threading, but is there any to simulate some simple thread that would act like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would be looking for `setInterval(updateMap, 45000)`

It will take the function you give it and run it every x milliseconds.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! Knew there had to be something nice and simple for it. Not quite familiar with all of javascripts little tools yet. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You want to have a WebWorker:

http://caniuse.com/#search=webworker

Answer (score 1):

The answer is indeed `setInterval()`. An example of using it to simulate multi-threading can be found here: http://www.sitepoint.com/multi-threading-javascript/